# Error while running Execute package task which call 3 child packages through command line utility

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am facing an issue while running execute package task through command line (Batch file). My parent package contains 3 child packages(through project reference), each child package is creating xml files from table data  in a for loop container(total 130 files needs to be generate) and each xml file is 70,250 KB size.

In Child package, I have a execute sql task which calls a stored procedure , from the stored procedure result set (string variable) creating xml file using script task.

My package Structure:

[image: My package Structure]

When I ran the parent package through BIDS, it's calling the child packages and files are getting generated. By using these generated xml files another team convert to json format. This entire process should be automate.

But when I ran the parent package through batch files, getting below system.out of memory exception while calling the child packages.

Batch Error

[image: Batch Error]

Can you please let me know what is the root cause for this exception.

Thanks in Advance. Venkat